# Kivy apk crashes with SQLite3 on android

Tags: android, python, sqlite, kivy

I have a small Kivy application using sqlite3
It works fine on windows , even on Ubuntu
I use Buildozer on VirtualBox to make the apk
The problem is that application runs normally until the time of inserting or reading from database. In thois point on androit , application crashes

My code is quite simple :

```
 conn = sqlite3.connect('mydb')
 first_name = self.first_name_text_input.text
 last_name = self.last_name_text_input.text
 sql = ''' INSERT INTO students(firstname,lastname)
           VALUES(?,?) '''
 cur = con.cursor()
 cur.execute(sql, (first_name, last_name))
```

in this point application crashes on android.
I have the database file in root directory with main.py when Buildozer makes the apk , so I guess database file is on the apk.

Do I have to do something else with the database file?
How can I debug this app to see why it crashes?
Where can I find the log file?

Thanks a lot

Kostas

Answer (score 1):

Try to connect your phone to a PC then enable USB Debugging on your phone's settings. Open your terminal on PC, then type `adb logcat *:E`. Open your kivy app on your phone and try to see the error on your PC when the app is crashed.